# Why Ingest plugin in elasticsearch is needed?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elk

I don't understand the importance of ingest attachment processor plugin. Why can I simply covert my pdf/doc to text and store it along with its actual path in the database. Ingest plugin first converts to base64 which also takes more space. So please tell me it's advantages over normal file-to-string method.

Comment: You don't need the ingest attachment plugin if are converting your pdf/doc **before** sending it to elasticsearch using an external tool.

Comment: But for ingest plugin also we have to convert files to base64 before sending it to elasticsearch using any external tool.

Comment: If you extract the text from your pdf or doc, you don't need the original file, you can index only the text, so you don't need the ingest plugin, the ingest attachment plugin is used when you want elasticsearch to read your file and index its content.

Comment: so you mean to say there are no performance differences in these two ways- 1. extracting flat text from the file (pdf, doc, Xls) and storing it as text along with its path in the database. 2. Base64 encoding the file first and indexing it using ingest plugin. Since in both ways, the content of the file is being indexed and I can run a search query on the content.

Comment: either way I have to some preprocessing 1. extract text 2. encode to base64. So why not follow simple way (1)